# Calculating amout of minutes between 2 times and divide it by amount of records

Tags: mysql, sql, count, timestamp, calculated-columns

How can we calculate the amount of minutes between 9 and 11 of all the  records togther (colum is generated). I also want to know how I can devide the output of that by the amount of records there are.

```
select  address,
        min(from_unixtime(time)) "Aankomsttijd",
        max(from_unixtime(time)) "Eindtijd",
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, min(from_unixtime(time)), max(from_unixtime(time))) "Minuten"
from    sensordata1
Where   from_unixTime(sensordata1.time) BETWEEN '2017/04/04' AND '2017/04/05' AND
        from_unixTime(sensordata1.time, '%H') BETWEEN 9 AND 11
group by address  
having Minuten > 2 AND Minuten < 1400
```

[Output](https://gyazo.com/e4ec0e4a2f976c2e5eb02f36116c41fd)

[Normal database as you can see "Minuten is not a real column"](https://gyazo.com/64ac9c150d3eceb99872481b603262f6)

What I want to get is all the minutes together as 1 amount and I want that to devide by the amount of records they calculated the minutes together.

Comment: Edit your question and add sample data and desired results *as a text table* in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that query you wrote as source for the calculation you want, like

```
select  sum(Minuten) total_minuten,
        count(*) records,
        sum(Minuten) / count(*) average_minuten
from    (
            select  address,
                    min(from_unixtime(time)) "Aankomsttijd",
                    max(from_unixtime(time)) "Eindtijd",
                    TIMESTAMPDIFF(
                      MINUTE,
                      min(from_unixtime(time)),
                      max(from_unixtime(time))
                    ) "Minuten"
            from    sensordata1
            Where   from_unixTime(sensordata1.time) BETWEEN '2017/04/04' AND '2017/04/05' AND
                    from_unixTime(sensordata1.time, '%H') BETWEEN 9 AND 11
            group by address  
            having Minuten > 2 AND Minuten < 1400
        ) t1
```

Comment: This works exactly like I wanted didnt need the amount of records but thx! <3